# how to include the app.js file in your blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i just have a complete clear blade template file which manually add the app.js file in local server machine . the error i faced is `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

here is the code i used `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` to blade file

whats wrong ?
could someone help me please ?

Comment: Without having any further information I'll assume that you don't have a file `public/js/app.js` ?

Comment: yes i don't have that file @apokryfos

Comment: If you don't have that file then you will get a 404 error (not found) when trying to access that file. If this is a new project I suggest you look at the [starter kits](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits) to get started with Laravel

Comment: i used Breeze & Blade package before but @apokryfos

Comment: Please describe your entire process i.e. how did you initialise your project what commands you ran what you run now to serve the site etc etc. You are doing something wrong somewhere but it's not clear exactly what that might be without more details

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure your webpack.mix.js or vite.config.js then do npm run. After that public/js files will be created.